# Making WMS GetFeatureInfo request gives Invalidpoint response?

Tags: openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

When I make a `GetFeatureInfo` request to a WMS service, I get an invalid point response. I wonder what is missing from my request.

My Layer definition :

```
var Parcels = new TileLayer({
      name: 'Parcels',
      source: new TileWMS({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',

        url: 'https://blabla.com',
        params: { 'LAYERS': ['myLayer'], 'TILED': true }

      })
    });
```

Map definition:

```
var mymap = new Map({
  layers: [Parcels],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  pixelRatio: 1,
  view: new View({

    center: fromLonLat([171.00, -45.00], 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 9

  })
});
```

Map event:

```
map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {

          var layer = findByName('Parcels');
          console.log(layer);
          var url = layer
            .getSource()
            .getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
              evt.coordinate,
              map.getView().getResolution(),
              map.getView().getProjection(),
              {
                'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/xml',
                'propertyName': 'parcel'

              }
          );
```

When I click on a map it returns:

`Invalid point (I parameter must be smaller than width parameter and J parameter must be smaller than height parameter.`

It makes a request with coordinates higher than the Width and Height of the Tile map.

```
https://blabla.com?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=myLayer&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fxml&propertyName=mylayerprop&I=706&J=282&WIDTH=516&HEIGHT=516&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&BBOX=-44.939169199785766%2C170.8956793139546%2C-44.93687999023354%2C170.8989132489774
```

I believe that this has to do with the openlayers [getGetFeatureInfoUrl](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_ImageWMS-ImageWMS.html#getGetFeatureInfoUrl) method options.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It might be a reprojection problem.  Does the WMS support any other projections?

Comment: If you replace GetFeatureInfo with GetMap in that request do get the map you were looking at when you clicked the point location

Comment: @nmtoken, I don't want the map, I want the Feature Information

Comment: Yes, of course, but the GetFeatureInfo request is a request for a pixel coordinate in a map image, the GFI request is the same as the GM, other than the request name, plus extra parameters related to pixel coord, and request response format.

Comment: So the issue to debug is, are the pixel coords wrong (if you get the same map as you clicked on...), else is the map size wrong (you have a different map image)

Answer (score 1):

There does appear to be a problem with `getGetFeatureInfoUrl` when a TileWMS layer and view use projections with different units.  Two meter based projections work correctly, e.g. I have a map with an EPSG:3857 TileWMS reprojected to the local UTM which works as expected.  The WMS also supports EPSG:4326 but when the TileWMS is changed to degree based EPSG:4326 a `getGetFeatureInfoUrl` call results in a url with invalid I or J parameters.  It's not even possible to simply transform the coordinates and use the layer projection ( this question also tried that [OpenLayers getGetFeatureInfoUrl in other projections](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286071/openlayers-getgetfeatureinfourl-in-other-projections) ) because the resolution is in different units.

Answer (score 0):

Your layer is tiled but your I/J pixel coordinates are not so they (nearly always) fall outside the tile. You need to adjust the coordinates to reflect the tile origin for this to work.

Comment: getGetFeatureInfoUrl should be doing that, and the calculation would be complex because in this case the tiles are being reprojected from an EPSG:4326 grid to an EPSG:3857 view. The 516 tile size also looks wrong when OpenLayers defaults to 256.

Comment: yeah, 516 is very odd 512 might make sense though

Comment: Yes, 516 is wrong I already fixed it. Is now 512, but even though it has the same issue.Sure @IanTurton, Yes in fact it is what the error describes but how do you adjust the coordinates to reflect the tile origin?